# Is $\sqrt{-\infty}$ one of the indeterminate cases?

Tags: limits, definition, education, indeterminate-forms

I'm sorry to ask this question , really there are many indeterminates cases in

the computation of limit of numerical functions such that :$\infty-\infty $, 
$0^0$ , $0*\infty$ $\cdots $ .

**My question here is:**

Is $\sqrt{-\infty}$ one of the indeterminate cases ?

**Note:** Really I would like to know more about the mathematical notion of indeterminate cases !!!!!

Thank you for any kind of help

Comment: I would either classify it as an undefined case, or divergent limit ie $\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)|=+\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indeterminate forms are ones where the limit can have different values depending on how the problematic numbers are reached - for example, a $0/0$ limit could be something like $x/x$ where the numerator and denominator approach 0 at the same rate, so they effectively cancel out; or it could be more like $x^2/x$ where the numerator approaches 0 "faster" and the limit goes to zero, or it could be more like $x/x^2$ where the denominator goes to 0 faster, so the limit has no bound (i.e. it's "infinite").

By comparison, if you have a limit where you're taking the square root of a function that goes negative, then you just have *undefined* values. Since there's no sensible value to give as you approach the limit point (assuming we're working in the real numbers), the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is not indeterminate. Note that for any positive real number $x$, $\sqrt{-x}$ is imaginary. Thus if you have some expression that is approaching $-\infty$ under a square root, then essentially, you are approaching infinity along the imaginary axis of the complex plane. As such, the magnitude of $\sqrt{-\infty}$ is always $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

if you find the form $\sqrt{-\infty}$,

this simply means that the definition domain (subset of $ \mathbb R$ ) of your function is not correct.

Comment: what you said is correct but i talk about it's  form !!!!!

Comment: if your function is defined from R to R, you will never get this form.

Comment: ‎$f(x)= \frac{x}{x} ‎$ is not defined at x=0 !!!!!

Comment: @user51189 where is $\sqrt{-\infty}$ here.

Comment: you meant if the function is defined we never get indeterminate form or any undefined form , just gave u a simple example

Comment: @user51189 here, we talk about $\sqrt{-\infty}$